# How many ways are there to divide the books?

Tags: combinatorics

I need to solve this problem but don't know where to start. I learned Counting Principles, but not permutations and combinations yet. Is this a permutation problem or combination problem? How to solve it?

> Twenty five books of the same kind are divided into 6 groups. Each group has at least one book and each group has a different number of books. How many ways are there to divide the books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part of your question: for permutations, order matters. Since these books are "of the same kind" and they are being divided into groups, order does *not* matter, so you're dealing with a combination.